# C# - WPF - Binding a List<int> to be printed in a StatusBar?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following in xaml:

```
<StatusBarItem Content="{Binding CorrectGuesses}" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

Here, `CorrectGuesses` is a `List<int>`. I'd like the code to output the actual numbers in the list to the statusbar, but right now it only shows `(Collection)`. What do I need to do so that the `StatusBarItem`'s  `Content` will be the items in the list? Thank you!

Comment: this is WPF right?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: Add a Converter , so that it prints all the numbers.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Converter , so that it prints all the numbers.

```
namespace AppConverters    
public class List2StringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            List<int> listNumbers = value as List<int>;
            // separator : , - / ... or white space
            return string.join("separator",listNumbers);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // To Do 
        }
    }
```

in your xaml page add this line to your window tag as schema:

```
xmlns:app="clr-namespace:AppConverters"
```

also add :

```
<Window.Resources>
        <app:List2StringConverter x:Key="L2StringConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

then use it as follows :

```
<StatusBarItem Content="{Binding CorrectGuesses,Converter={StaticResource L2StringConverter}}" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<StatusBarItem Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CorrectGuesses}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</StatusBarItem>
```

Comment: This seems to work, except that it doesn't put any spaces between the numbers, so they're undistinguishable.

Comment: of course not, its a textblock. either use a label, add margins to the text block or align it any other way. easiest would be Margin="3,0" within the textblock